# Rspec is not creating database records accessible from poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, poltergeist

I'm having terrible trouble getting Poltergeist and RSpec to play together nicely.

I've written the following test:

```
  it "allows the trainer to view a runner" do
    visit '/'
    all(:xpath,'//a[@id="get-started"]').first.click
    fill_in :name, with: "New Admin"
    fill_in :email, with: "admin@test.org"
    fill_in :password, with: "letmein"
    fill_in :password_confirmation, with: "letmein"
    all(:xpath,'//input[@id="get-started-submit"]').first.click
    @runner_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:runner, name: "Axel", email: "axel@test.org")
    visit '/runners/axel'
    debugger
```

Effectively, what the above is doing is registering 'New Admin' with the password, 'letmein', then trying to view the runner profile page for 'Axel'.

Where the debugger interrupts, I can see that @runner_1 (Axel) has been created:

```
Runner.friendly.find('axel')

>> #<Runner id: 2, email: "axel.manzano@hotmail.fr",........>
```

However, when trying to visit '/runners/axel', Poltergeist reports:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```

It's not an issue with routes, or anything like that.

Having explored this bug a little further, in fact, it seems anything created in the test file doesn't actually get set up in the environment that Poltergeist is accessing.

I can't seem to understand why.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are, you are using "transactional fixtures" in rspec. This means that each test run in a database transaction, which is rolled back at the end of test, so that each test has a clean database.

Other threads/programs can **not** see what is going on in the transaction. Poltergeist runs the server in the separate thread, which means that it can not see anything that is written to the database in rspec (although it can be accessed directly from the rspec code).

There is [a description of this phenomenon on the capybara homepage](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup). The solution is to disable the transactional feature in rspec-rails and use something like DatabaseCleaner to reset the database after a test.

This will work, but unfortunately truncating or deleting the database contents is somewhat slower than they would with the transactional approach - this is why the tranasactions are the default in the first place.